# Scraping with Nokogiri to Create an Object from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to parse the name and price of deals. I created a rake task to save the parse info by creating a new deal from the traveldeal model.

However, when I run the rake command, the new deal isn't created/saved even though no errors were returned. I made sure to include `resource :traveldeals` in my routes.rb.

I think it has something to do with the actions in my traveldeals controller. Any tips?

travel_deals.rake

```
desc "Fetch travel deals"
task :fetch_travel => :environment do

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

  #Traveldeal.find_all_by_price(nil).each do |traveldeal|     <<WRONG!
    url = "http://www.groupon.com/deals/ga-flamingo-conferences-resort-spa?c=all&p=0"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))


    title = doc.at_css("#content//h2/a").text
    price = doc.at_css("#amount").text[/[0-9\.]+/]
    link = doc.at_css("#content//h2/a")[:href]

    Traveldeal.create(:title => title, :price => price, :url => link)
  #end
end
```

traveldeals_controller.rb

```
class TraveldealsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @traveldeal = Traveldeal.find(params[:id])     
  end

  def new
    @traveldeal = Traveldeal.new
  end

  def create
  @traveldeal = Traveldeal.new(params[:traveldeal])
  end
end
```

traveldeal.rb

```
class Traveldeal < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :title, :price, :url
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :price, :presence => true
  validates :url, :presence => true
end
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Made changes per ksol's answer.

EDIT: I am now getting this error in my development.log.

`[1m[36mTraveldeal Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "traveldeals".* FROM "traveldeals" WHERE "traveldeals"."price" IS NULL[0m`

Comment: Finally able to fix the problem. I commented out the mistake in my answer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` creates an object, but does not save it to the database. Either use `create` instead, or call `save` explicitly

**EDIT**

In your rake task, you're building your object with setting the `url` attribute, but in your model, you're expecting his presence (via a validation). So yep, the object won't be saved.

Comment: Changing it to ` traveldeal.create(:title => title, :price => price)` still doesn't save.

Comment: after `save` or `create`, check `traveldeal.errors`. If there is no errors, then we're both missing something

Comment: I don't quite follow. Do you mind elaborating? I'm still new to rails.

Comment: When making a call to `save` (or `create`), if there was an error preventing the object to be saved, the field `errors` is filled with informations about what prevented it. Usually, it's a validation that failed. And I just noticed there's a missing field in your rake task, cf my updated post.

Comment: Made the changes, but it still isn't saving.

Comment: I should really learn to read sometimes. So you're iterating on some Traveldeals, and you want to create other traveldeals, is that it ? if so, you need to use `Traveldeal.create` (calling the class, not the object)

Comment: Yes, ksol, that is exactly what I'm trying to do. I made the change to `Traveldeal.create` It still isn't saving :/ I appreciate your help though.

Comment: You forgot to set your `url` attribute as accessible too. The mass-assignment in create is failing because of that

Comment: I just saw that too and made the change